# How to solve encoding issues in a shiny app

Tags: r, shiny

Any tips to solve encoding problem. I am not able to generate the up (`↑`) and down (`↓`) arrows in the code below. When running, the following warning message appears:

```
Warning messages:
1: unable to translate 'Maximize <U+2191>' to native encoding 
2: unable to translate 'Minimize <U+2193>' to native encoding
```

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        column(
          width = 6,
          selectInput("maxmin", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize"),
                      choices = list("Maximize \u2191" = 1, "Minimize \u2193" = 2), selected = "")
        )
      )),
    
    mainPanel(
      
    ))
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use HTML code for the arrows and proceed like this:

```
library(shiny)

choicesNames <- list("Minimize", "Maximize")
choicesHTML <- list("Minimize &#8595;", "Maximize &#8593;")
choices <- setNames(choicesNames, choicesHTML)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("select", label = "Select", choices = NULL),
  textOutput("txt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  updateSelectizeInput(
    session, "select",
    choices = choices,
    options = list(render = I("
      {
        item:   function(item, escape) { return '<div>' + item.label + '</div>'; },
        option: function(item, escape) { return '<div>' + item.label + '</div>'; }
      }
    "))
  )
  
  output$txt <- renderText({
    paste("You chose", input$select)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

---

Another option is to use my package [shinySelect](https://github.com/stla/shinySelect) and **fontawesome** icons for the arrows.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinySelect)
library(bslib)
library(fontawesome)


choices <- HTMLchoices(
  labels = list(
    tags$span("Minimize", fa_i("arrow-alt-circle-down")),
    tags$span("Maximize", fa_i("arrow-alt-circle-up"))
  ),
  values = list("minimize", "maximize")
)

styles <- list(
  borderBottom = "5px solid orange",
  color = list(selected = "lime", otherwise = "pink"),
  backgroundColor = list(selected = "cyan", otherwise = "seashell")
)

ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = bs_theme(version = 4),
  titlePanel("shinySelect example"),
  selectControlInput(
    "inputid", 
    label = tags$h1("Make a choice", style = "color: red;"),
    optionsStyles = styles,
    choices = choices,
    selected = "minimize",
    multiple = FALSE,
    animated = TRUE
  ),
  br(),
  verbatimTextOutput("textOutput")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$textOutput <- renderPrint({
    sprintf("You selected: %s", input$inputid)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an alternate solution.  Solutions provided by @Stephane Laurent are great. To translate unicode points to UTF-8, you can use `chr_unserialise_unicode()` from `rlang` package. Try this

```
library(shiny)
library(rlang)

ll <- chr_unserialise_unicode("<U+2193>")
uu <- chr_unserialise_unicode("<U+2191>")

choicesNames <- list(1,2)
choiceValues <- list(sprintf("Minimize %s",ll),sprintf("Maximize %s",uu))
choices <- setNames(choicesNames, choiceValues)

ui <- fluidPage(
          selectInput("maxmin", label = h5("Maximize or Minimize"), choices = NULL), 
          textOutput("mytxt")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  updateSelectInput(session, "maxmin", choices = choices )

  output$mytxt <- renderText({
    paste("You chose", input$maxmin)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```